# What kind of distribution do I have if the histogram bins are exponentially increasing and it looks about normal?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[A picture is worth a thousand words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv33f.jpg)

Here's the situation. I've got a distribution of data that is heavily skewed to the right, and when I change my binning to be exponentially increasing (I used powers of 2 arbitrarily), it looks normal-ish.

At first, I thought I had a lognormal distribution, but now I think I have that definition backwards (I would have to take the log of the values and then plot. That doesn't help me here).

Now I am thinking Poisson, but it's been too long since I've taken a statistics class to remember how to use that.

I appreciate any help. My next step is to dig up my old stats book to see if I can figure anything out.

On my way out, I thought of an exponential distribution, but I don't know how to use those. If it's this, still tell me. I don't know if this is actually Poisson or if one is a generality if the other.

Comment: I don't think you had the definition backwards? Take log of the values on the x-axis.

Comment: You helped me realize a mistake - I took the log of my values and plotted them, but for some reason Excel decided I needed a pareto chart, so it ordered my histogram. Obviously, it didn't look right. A bunch of confusion because Excel thought it was helping. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've decided it's lognormal (ish... close enough for my purposes). When I plotted the log of my data earlier, Excel decided I wanted a Pareto chart, so it looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRbcF.jpg). I didn't notice until now.

But I fixed it and now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miqIu.jpg).